# How to `touch` files recursively?

Tags: command-line, files, touch-command

I need to change the timestamp of about 5000 files.

Typing `touch file1.txt`, `touch file2.txt` will take me forever.

Is there a way to do something in the lines of `touch -R *`?

Comment: did you mean this `touch file{1..3}.txt` ?

Comment: You didn't specify which shell you are using, but with zsh, `touch **/*` is convenient.

Comment: @Marc Glisse Keep in mind that the argument list easily gets too long.

Comment: In bash you need to set globstar before you can use touch **

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can use [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/find.1.html) command to find all your files and execute `touch` on every found file using `-exec`

```
find . -type f -exec touch {} +
```

If you want to filter your result only for text files, you can use

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec touch {} +
```

Comment: And for a dry run, just leave out the `-exec touch {} +` part, and it'll print to your terminal what it *would* have affected.

Comment: What if I only want to change the access time, not the modification time? Should it be "find  -type f  -exec touch -a {} +"?

Comment: @giltsl g_p's answer works verbatim for me

Comment: It's worth noting that the man page (Ubuntu 19.10) for `find` suggests it is more secure to use `-execdir` rather than `-exec` as `-execdir` runs each command from the directory in which the `find` result is located. It also says that when invoked from a shell, "[the curly brace pair] should be quoted (for example, '{}') to protect it from interpretation by shells".

Comment: Leaving out `-type f`, it will also affect directories:
`find . -execdir touch '{}' +`
(also incorporated other improvements as mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

g_p's answer makes the timestamp "now" but if for instance you forgot the cp -p parameter and need to replace timestamps with their originals recursively without recopying all the files. Here is what worked for me:

```
find /Destination -exec bash -c 'touch -r "${0/Destination/Source}" "$0"' {} \;
```

This assumes a duplicate file/ folder tree of Source: `/Source` and Destination: `/Destination`

1. `find` searches the Destination for all files & dirs (which need timestamps) and `-exec ... {}` runs a command for each result.
2. `bash -c ' ... '` executes a shell command using bash.
3. `$0` holds the find result.
4. `touch -r {timestamped_file} {file_to_stamp}` uses a bash replace command `${string/search/replace}` to set timestamp source appropriately.
5. the Source and Destination directories are quoted to handle dirs with spaces.